# Sentry-sdk: set tags through extra keyword on logger

Tags: python, sentry

I'm upgrading my current code using the `raven` library to the `sentry-sdk` library. The Client is created as follows:

```py
sentry_sdk.init('<sentry_dsn>', integrations=[LoggingIntegration()])
```

I used to be able to create a dict with a `tags` key and pass it to the logger.exception-function using the `extra` keyword:

```py
extra_dict = {'tags': {'a': 'b'}}
logging.getLogger('...').exception(error, *args, extra=extra_dict, **kwargs)
```

This would result in the tags appearing on the Sentry website. However, this is no longer the case with the new library. Is there another approach without requiring the `sentry_sdk.set_tag(..., ...)` as it requires importing the `sentry_sdk` in this util function of mine.